# Strange UItextView behavior setting range within textViewDidChangeSelection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am getting a strange behavior setting the selectedRange property for a textView within the textViewDidChangeSelection delegate.

My code in viewDidLoad is:

```
hiddenTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
//[hiddenTextView setHidden:YES];
_hiddenTextViewText=@"ulrd";
hiddenTextView.text = _hiddenTextViewText;
hiddenTextView.delegate = self;
_hiddenTextViewDefaultRange = NSMakeRange(2,0);
hiddenTextView.selectedRange = _hiddenTextViewDefaultRange;   //horizontal and vertical center of the textview
[self.view addSubview:hiddenTextView];

[hiddenTextView becomeFirstResponder];
if (_keyboardShown)
    [hiddenTextView resignFirstResponder];
```

I define the textViewDidChangeSelection as follows:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {

    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)textView.selectedRange.location);


    if (textView.selectedRange.location != _hiddenTextViewDefaultRange.location)
    {
        hiddenTextView.selectedRange = _hiddenTextViewDefaultRange;
    }

}
```

I set a 4 character text and put the selection index in position 2 (middle). The result is that if I press up arrow on the keyboard in simulator NSLog outputs 0 (start of text) and then 2 (reseting the position) which is correct. If I press up again it does the same thing so still correct. Problem is that if I hit up x times I have to hit down equal times before I am able to go to the end of the text (position 4).
I tried resetting the position with a UIButton instead of doing it programmatically and there it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you connected a keyboard to a real device and tested this? If it only happens in the simulator it doesn't matter.

Comment: Just tried it. Same thing happens on the iPad with a bluetooth keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to overcome the problem. Instead of:

```
hiddenTextView.selectedRange = _hiddenTextViewDefaultRange;
```

I used:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            textView.selectedRange = hiddenTextViewDefaultRange;
        });
```

...to execute the command async. It worked, however I am not sure why it needed to be like that.